# Make request from apple watch requests via ios app

Tags: objective-c, networking, watchos, watchconnectivity

Now I'm developing apple watch extension and I use WatchConnectivity. 
Can I send message to ios app ios application make a request ?

Who can make a request to the server ios app or watch extension ?

P.S. Use AFNetworking to work with server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to send notification to ios App to make request

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:dictSendMessage replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage) {
} errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    }];
```

And you can receive that notification with this delegate method in ios app

```
-(void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull))replyHandler
{
}
```

Note : You can also request to server from watch app it self with the help of

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *taskDownload = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
}];
// Start the task.
    [taskDownload resume];
```